# Discrete mathematics - Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n W_k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n L_k^2. $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a round-robin tournament with $n$ players $P_1, P_2,\ldots,P_n$, each of the players plays a match against every other player. There are no ties, so each match ends in a win for one side and a loss for the other side. Let $W_k$ denote the number of wins of player $P_k$, and let $L_k$ denote the number of losses of $P_k$. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n W_k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n L_k^2. $$

This is one of the questions we presented in one session to contest preparation PUTNAM. It turns out that I can't get from the problem. Could someone just give me a hint? (Please, don't give me the answer. Simply, an argument that can help me advance in the problem or theorem might suffice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Want to show $∑_{k=1}^n (W^2_k - L^2_k) = 0$, difference of squares...

Full solution (mouseover):

> $$  ∑_{k=1}^n (W^2_k - L^2_k) = ∑_{k=1}^n \underbrace{(W_k + L_k)}_{=n}(W_k - L_k) = n∑_{k=1}^n (W_k-L_k) = 0$$ since for every win, there is a loss.